# Non-Legendary Planeswalkers

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-planeswalkers

If a Planeswalker in Magic the Gathering wasn't Legendary when it was printed (before *Dominaria* in 2018, e.g. [Liliana, Death's Majesty](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLiliana%2c%5d%2b%5bDeath%27s%5d%2b%5bMajesty%5d)), would you be allowed to have two of that same Planeswalker card in gameplay?

[image: Liliana, Death's Majesty]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, because even if it's not printed on the card, they're still Legendary due to errata:

> 306.4. Previously, planeswalkers were subject to a “planeswalker uniqueness rule” that stopped a player from controlling two planeswalkers of the same planeswalker type. This rule has been removed and planeswalker cards printed before this change have received errata in the Oracle card reference to have the legendary supertype. Like other legendary permanents, they are subject to the “legend rule” (see rule 704.5j).

If you look at the Oracle text of [Liliana, Death's Majesty](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLiliana%2c%5d%2b%5bDeath%27s%5d%2b%5bMajesty%5d), it says

> **Types:** Legendary Planeswalker — Liliana

instead of just "Planeswalker — Liliana" so it *is* legendary and you can only have one of her in play. But there could be newer planeswalkers printed in the future which *aren't* legendary, and of those you *would* be able to have multiple at the same time.

A few currently existing options to make non-legendary or at least multiple copies of planeswalkers (thanks to @AlexP and @ArcanistLupus for the suggestions):

- [Jace, Cunning Castaway](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJace%2c%20Cunning%20Castaway%5d)
- [Helm of the Host](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHelm%20of%20the%20Host%5d) for a planeswalker turned into a creature (e.g. with [Memnarch](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMemnarch%5d) and [March of the Machines](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarch%20of%20the%20Machines%5d))
- [Mirror Gallery](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirror%20Gallery%5d)

Comment: What are the newer planewalkers where you can have multiple of them at the same time?

Comment: Sorry, I vaguely recalled there being a few, but I must have misremembered. Still, it's possible that they'll print them in the future.

Comment: @RandomKiwi [Jace, Cunning Castaway](https://scryfall.com/card/xln/60/jace-cunning-castaway) tokens

Comment: True @AlexP, those token planeswalkers are not legendary, but I was wondering whether there were any non-legendary planeswalker which you could cast form your hand.

Comment: I don't understand why Wizards of the Coast didn't specify Liliana, Death's Majesty to be legendary on the card itslef.

Comment: Because the rule was changed *after* printing the card. They can't just give everybody new copies ...

Comment: You have plenty of examples with what you have so no need to add this, but I just want to mention that the card Spark Double was pretty much created to do exactly what was described here.

Comment: And of course Gideon can make himself a creature.

Comment: @Acccumulation I thought of that, but it doesn't help for Helm of the Host...

Answer (score 4):

You can have multiple planeswalkers in play as long as the card name is different. For example: [Garruk, Cursed Huntsman](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGarruk%2c%20Cursed%20Huntsman%5d) and [Garruk, Wildspeaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGarruk%2c%20Wildspeaker%5d). I choose Garruk because of the new card from Throne of Eldraine: Garruk, Cursed Huntsman. His first ability says create 2 wolves with when a created wolf die you put a loyalty counter on **every** Garruk in play.

> 306.4.: Previously, planeswalkers were subject to a “planeswalker uniqueness rule” that stopped a player from controlling two planeswalkers of the same planeswalker type. This rule has been removed and planeswalker cards printed before this change have received errata in the Oracle card reference to have the legendary supertype. Like other legendary permanents, they are subject to the “legend rule” (see rule 704.5j).

> 704.5j: If a player controls two or more legendary permanents with the same name, that player chooses one of them, and the rest are put into their owners’ graveyards. This is called the “legend rule.”

So as long as the two planeswalkers don't have the same card name, you can have them both on the battlefield simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to use two of the same Planeswalker at the same time is to duplicate it with Spark Double or a card with similar effect.